# Paralell specflow with [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] doesn't work correctlly

Tags: nunit, specflow

Paralell specflow with [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] doesn't work correctlly, I have 4 test in two differents features, and Nunit runner opens 4 browsers, and should be 2 one for feature....

Comment: You need to look at the generated NUnit test code from SpecFlow. It sounds as if more than one fixture per feature is generated. Naturally, NUnit knows nothing about features, only fixtures.